# Как определить наличие класса у всех элементов массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив из названий полей формы страницы регистрации (id-шники этих полей). Полей может быть много. Для примера:

```
var params=['name', 'city', 'password'];
```

Как проверить что все поля имеют класс success (универсальная функция,которая возвращает true, если все элементы страницы с id-шником из params имеют класс success), т.е.:

$('#name').hasClass('success')&&$('#city').hasClass('success')&&$('#password').hasClass('success');

Как написать функцию:

```
function(params){
  /*что написать?*/
}
```

Comment: `$(params.map(p=> \`#{p}.success\`).join(',')).length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно выбрать все элементы из указанного массива с указанными классами, и сравнить количество выбранных элементов с количеством элементов в массиве:

```
$(params.map(p=> `#${p}.success`).join(',')).length == params.length
```

Если результат сравнения `false`- значит классы `success` присутствуют не у всех элементов из массива.

---

Так же можно воспользоваться методом [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
params.every(p=>$(`#${p}`).hasClass('success'));
```

Comment: есть одна поправочка, может быть что не все элементы с данными id были на странице, хотя топикстартера это и не беспокоит, в целом решение хорошее, и даже без жуквери не страшно будет выглядеть.